# Strange behavior with Menu inside cells and sheetView

Tags: swift, listview, swiftui

I would like to add `Menu` in the cells of my list but this causes a strange behavior when I want to open the sheet view.
I get the following message:

> [Presentation] Attempt to present
> <*TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView*:
> 0x1620b0800> on
> <*TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier*_:
> 0x161811800> (from
> <*TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier*_:
> 0x161811800>) which is already presenting
> <_UIContextMenuActionsOnlyViewController: 0x16051de40>.

I feel like the sheet view wants to open at the same time as the menu.
How can I solve the problem?

Here is an example code that illustrates my problem:

```
struct Item: Identifiable{
let id: Int
let marque: String
let reference: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items = [Item(id: 1, marque: "Schneider", reference: "123333"),     Item(id: 2, marque: "Siemens", reference: "1234444"), Item(id: 3, marque: "Beck", reference: "1233"), Item(id: 4, marque: "Aron", reference: "133449")]
    @State private var selectedItem: Item?

var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
            HStack {
                Text(item.marque)
                Spacer()
                Menu(content: {
                    Button("Edit") {}
                    Button("Delete") {}
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                })
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                self.selectedItem = item
            }
        }
    }
    .sheet(item: $selectedItem) { item in
        VStack{
            Text(item.marque)
            Text(item.reference)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It is still unclear that what you want to achieve. Can you please explain do you want to open only sheet or menu or both when button is pressed?

Comment: for example if I tap on the first ellipse of the list and then I want to open the sheet view of the first cell it does not work. The message in the terminal above is displayed when I press the ellipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sheet is trying to present at the same time as Menu, as we have the `TapGesture` on the `HStack` which contains both the `row` and the `Menu`.

What is happening behind the scene? :-

1. When we tap the ellipse (`Menu`), SwiftUI will try to present the Menu.
2. But as we also have the `Tap Gesture` over the `Row`, it will update the `selectedItem` to item.
3. And as the `selectedItem` updates, as it is binding to the sheet, SwiftUI will then also try to present sheet.
4. And the error log prints in the console: `“Attempt to present which is already presenting”`. It tells you that as `Self` which is already presenting a `Menu` and therefor can not present the sheet.

So in order to fix this, let’s update our ViewTree. We will keep the Text and Menu in different stack and only add gesture to the text (`Row`).

```
List {
    ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
        HStack {
            HStack {
                Text(item.marque)
                Spacer()
            }
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture {
                self.selectedItem = item
            }

            Menu(content: {
                Button("Edit") {}
                Button("Delete") {}
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
            })
        }
    }
}
.sheet(item: $selectedItem) { item in
    VStack{
        Text(item.marque)
        Text(item.reference)
    }
}
```

This way tapping the `Menu` will not update the `selectedItem` property.